# How to get container ID from within the container itself

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to get the container ID of the running container at the startup time. This is to use that information in service health check apis.

I got a loadbalancer sitting in front of a fleet of containers, and runs periodic health checks via `https://service-n.api.com/health`. Idea is to return the container information with the api responses.

I'm using docker-compose to spinup docker containers, it'd be great if there's a way to pass the container id as environment variable to the container, like below.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: my.registry.com/pq-api:1.0.0
    container_name: my-container
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ID: "{{.ID}}"
```

Answer (score 6):

The container Id is already available by default to all containers inside the environment variable `HOSTNAME`

```
$ docker run alpine env

   HOSTNAME=....
   ....
```

Comment: Seems it's built in to alpine base image. I'm using centurylink/ca-certs and it doesn't have that. Can we rely on HOSTNAME as the container id?